# Match and RegEx in C# form?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, c#-4.0, console

Can RegEx and Match be used in a Windows Form?
I know they work in the console applications...

I'm trying to convert a Console app to a Windows Form Application.

Comment: It works, no matter whether this is a web / console / forms/ wpf / ce. So why are you asking, have you tried it and faced some issues?

Comment: Please let us know why you think regular expressions might not work.

Comment: Because I was getting errors that said that "RegEx doesn't exist in the current context"

Then I looked back at the Console App. and realized that it was using the "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;" so I just added it on top.

Thanks

Comment: Beware of code-under-button programming (that is, all your logic is in the form code). C# is an object-oriented language; creating new classes is frequently the best way to accomplish tasks. These new classes could be called from WinForm, Console, Web, etc. apps - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RegEx` can be used in anything that can access the .Net Framework. WinForms, Console, WPF, code-behind in an ASP.Net website, etc.

You could even create an instance of the `RegEx` class in ColdFusion using [.Net integration](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/features/netintegration/) (crazy, I know)!

Comment: This was a really bad question... Thanks anyway for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most .NET library functions can be used in any type of application.

Comment: This was a really bad question... Thanks anyway for answering.